# Implement authentication for file download

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, iis

I am working on a WPF application. In One of the Module ,we are having a file download section. The application will download two files from web server. We have implemented it using WebClient.  But  the issue is, any person can download these files , if they  know the url of file.  So we have to implement some Authentication for the download part.

As my know lodge, we have two methods to implement the Authentication

1.Put some access permission to web server folder. And pass these credentials from WPF web client, while download the file.

2.Use a WCF service method to download the files.  So that we can download the file after a proper authentication

Please guide me a way. If any other begetter way please let me know.

Any help would be appreciable.

Best Regards,

Ranish

Comment: how can any person know URL ? download it in background @Ranish

Comment: Any one can see it using fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

When using MVC its as simple as placing the Authorize attribute on the specific action. 
e.g

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Download()
{}
```